# Zend Framework Router Hostname and Multi-Language support

Tags: php, zend-framework, router, hostname, chain

Last two days I was fighting with Zend Framework Router and still didn't find solution.

Existing project has 2 different modules which work with the same domain e.g. *www.domain1.com*:

- **default** - Contains public information, can be accessed via **www.domain1.com**
- **admin** - Administrator interface, can be accessed via **www.domain1.com/admin**

Project is multi-langual and to keep language code it is transmitted as first parameter of every URL, e.g. **www.domain1.com/en/**  **www.domain1.com/en/admin**

Part of code which takes care is next plugin:

```
class Foo_Plugin_Language extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

const LANGUAGE_KEY = 'lang';

 public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{


    $languagesRegexp = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $this->_bootstrap->getLanguages()));

    $routeLang = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':' . self::LANGUAGE_KEY,
        array(self::LANGUAGE_KEY => $this->_bootstrap->getLanguage()->toString()),
        array(self::LANGUAGE_KEY => $languagesRegexp)
    );

    $router = $this->getFrontController()->getRouter();

    $router->addDefaultRoutes();

    $chainSeparator = '/';

    foreach ($router->getRoutes() as $name => $route) {

        $chain = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain();
        $chain
            ->chain($routeLang, $chainSeparator)
            ->chain($route, $chainSeparator);

        $new_name = $this->_formatLanguageRoute($name);

        $router->addRoute($new_name, $chain);
    }

    protected function _formatLanguageRoute($name)
    {
        $suffix = '_' . self::LANGUAGE_KEY;
        if (substr($name, -strlen($suffix)) == $suffix) return $name;
        return $name . '_' . self::LANGUAGE_KEY;
    }

public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $lang = $request->getParam(self::LANGUAGE_KEY, null);

    $this->_bootstrap->setLanguage($lang);
    $actual_lang = $this->_bootstrap->getLanguage()->toString();

    $router = $this->getFrontController()->getRouter();
    $router->setGlobalParam(self::LANGUAGE_KEY, $lang);

    // Do not redirect image resize requests OR get js, css files
    if (preg_match('/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$/i', $request->getPathInfo())) {
        return true;
    }

    // redirect to appropriate language
    if ($lang != $actual_lang) {

        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');

        $params = array(self::LANGUAGE_KEY => $actual_lang);
        $route = $this->_formatLanguageRoute($router->getCurrentRouteName());

        return $redirector->gotoRouteAndExit($params, $route, false);
    }
}

}
```

One of the first question is what do you think about such way to provide multi-lang support. What I've noticed is that all this chains dramatically decrease operation speed of the server, response time from the server is about 4 seconds...

**Main question is:** Currently I have to implement such feature: I have domain www.domain2.com that should work just with single module e.g. "foobar"... and it should be available via second url... or, of course, it should work like **www.domain1.com/en/foobar** by default...

To provide this functionality in Bootstrap class I'be implemented such part of code

```
// Instantiate default module route
$routeDefault = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
    array(),
    $front->getDispatcher(),
    $front->getRequest()
);

$foobarHostname = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
        'www.domain2.com',
        array(
            'module' => 'foobar'
        )
    );

$router->addRoute("foobarHostname", $foobarHostname->chain($routeDefault));
```

And that is not working and as I've found routeDefault always rewrite found correct model name "foobar" with value "default"

Then I've implemented default router like this:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':controller/:action/*',
        array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index'
        );

    );
```

But that still didn't work, and started work without language only when I comment "routeStartup" method in Foo_Plugin_Language BUT I need language support, I've played a lot with all possible combinations of code and in the end made this to provide language support by default:

```
class Project_Controller_Router_Route extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module
```

{
    /**
     * @param string $path
     * @param bool $partial
     * @return array
     */
    public function match($path, $partial = false)
    {
        $result = array();

```
    $languageRegexp = '%^\/([a-z]{2})(/.*)%i';

    if (preg_match($languageRegexp, $path, $matches)) {
        $result['lang'] = $matches[1];
        $path = $matches[2];
    }

    $parentMatch = parent::match($path);

    if (is_array($parentMatch)) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $parentMatch);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

}

So language parameter was carefully extracted from path and regular processed left part as usual...

But when I did next code I was not able to get access to the foobar module via www.domain2.com url, because of module name in request was always "default"

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    /** @var Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite $router */
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $dispatcher = $front->getDispatcher();
    $request = $front->getRequest();
    $routerDefault = new Project_Controller_Router_Route(array(), $dispatcher, $request);

    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();

    $router->addRoute('default', $routerDefault); 

    $foobarHostname = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
        'www.domain2.com',
        array(
            'module' => 'foobar'
        )
    );

$router->addRoute("foobar", $foobarHostname->chain($routerDefault));
```

Instead of **summary**:

- Problem is that I should implement feature that will provide access for the secondary domain to the specific module of ZendFramework, and I should save multi-language support. And I cannot find a way, how to manage all of this...
- Secondary question is about performance of chain router, it makes site work very-very slow...

Comment: Addressing your points: 1. if you configure your vhost to route through to the project, then zend can manage the routing to a module http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname , 2. You could cache the router for performance, memcache will be the fastest

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved problem with multilanguage page is in this thread:
[Working with multilanguage routers in Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313493/working-with-multilanguage-routers-in-zend/16487818#16487818) (last post).

Ofcourse my sollution need some caching to do, but I think it will solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I already have almost the same system for translations. Problem is that when I add **Route Hostname** in application bootstrap it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why this happens, it simply ignores this route...
Can you try to apply Hostname router in scope of your project and verify if it work?